# Blocks not generating while mining on a private Ethereum network

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I am using Ethereum Geth(v.1.6.7) on a Ubuntu(16.04.3 LTS) Virtual Machine(on Virtual Box).
I have setup a private Ethereum blockchain with 2 nodes(on 2 different terminals).

Now I am mining from each node for about 4 hours now but there doesn't seem to be any new block(s) forming. (i.e. BlockNumber is still on 0 after about 4hours).

Even though the hashingRate is regularly changing and the 'eth.mining' variable returns true.

I did my research and everything seems to be setup as required. For the genesis block, I set up the difficulty as 0X20. Which should have given me the first block within a few minutes.

Basic specs for the VM are: 6GB RAM and have a processing time of i7 2nd gen CPU allocated.

Looking for help on what could I be doing wrong. And what do I need to change to generate the first block?

Comment: check this link : https://media.consensys.net/how-to-build-a-private-ethereum-blockchain-fbf3904f337 it shows generation of blocks but its using go language.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia Thanks. My work here is almost the same. The other difference is that mine uses 2 nodes.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia I will try out that tutorial as well later today :)

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked. I got the first block through mining only.

I decided to run geth, make peers and mine, directly on my Windows 8.1 instead of using the Ubuntu VM. All the other configurations were the same.

It let it mine overnight and it took approximately 9 hours to make the first block.

I am assuming that the mining took so much time because of old hardware combined with overheating.